# Raspi3 model b USB to Rs232 not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, serial, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to do a simple hexdump from the port /dev/ttyUSB0 which is connected to USB to rs232 connector. Hexdump and all my scripts worked with pi2 not with this one. Is there any particular upgrade to be done to make hexdump work ??